# Can't start Docker traefik container with ssl

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, traefik

I'm trying to run traefik with ssl - 
on a self signed certificate. 
this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
traefik:
image: traefik
restart: unless-stopped
command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO --defaultEntryPoints='https' --entryPoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS:/certs/cert.pem,/certs/key.pem" --entryPoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
ports:
  - '80:80'
  - '443:443'
  - '8080:8080'
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - ./certs:/certs/
```

When running `docker-compose up` -  i'm getting this error in log:

`level=error msg="Error creating TLS config: bad TLS Certificate KeyFile format, expected a path"`

after that:

`level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: bad TLS Certificate KeyFile format, expected a path`

And then:

`traefik exited with code 1`

I'm running Docker Version 17.06.0 on a Mac

Any clue on what could be the issue here ?

Comment: Check your certificate files and see if they both have "----- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY -------" and "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----". If not then you are not using the right format of certificate